# jQuery multiple sliders on a single form

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I have multiple slider forms in my page: like this  [one](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#steps). For just one it works fine, but for multiple slider forms the php post values return empty.

So far I have:

jQuery:

```
    $(function() {
    $( ".slider" ).slider({
        value:0,
        min: -1,
        max: 1,
        step: 0.01,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( ".amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
        }
    });
    $( ".amount" ).val( "$" + $( ".slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
```

My html:

```
<div class="demo">
    <form action="next.php" method="post">
        <p>
            <label class="amount">How strong is your relationship with this person?</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="first_question" />
        </p>
        <div class="slider"></div>
        <br/>
        <p>
            <label class="amount">How would you feel asking this friend to loan you $100 or more?</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="second_question" />
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

How can I correctly pass the post values?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you have here. As far as I can tell, your form has two hidden inputs, but no values associated with them. When you submit your form, I would imagine no values will be submitted for those input fields because they A. have no default values and B. there's no way for a user to input values since they're hidden.

Comment: Your slider code is trying to change the value of label tags `$( ".amount" ).val(...` (which doesn't even have a value attribute), not the hidden form fields.

Comment: Where is the second slider in your html above? I'm looking for another <div class="slider"></div>.

Comment: Ops, I was unware of that. Thanks for warning me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `div` for each slider you want and give the sliders an attribute that links them to the `input` - This is an example using your HTML as a starting point :

```
<div class="demo">
    <form id="myform" action="next.php" method="post">
        <p>
            <label class="amount">How strong is your relationship with this person?</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="first_question"/>
        </p>
        <div class="slider" id="first"></div>
        <br/>
        <p>
            <label class="amount">How would you feel asking this friend to loan you $100 or more?</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="second_question"/>
        </p>
        <div class="slider" id="second"></div>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

​

Then use the following to initialise the sliders :

```
$(".slider").slider({
    step: 1,
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    value: 5,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("input[name=" + $(this).attr("id") + "_question]").val(ui.value);
    }
});
```

The important part here is the setting of the value - it grabs the `id` attribute from the slider div adds `_question` to it and then finds the `input` with a matching `name` attribute.

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/bQncM/)

Note : you have no default values specified on the `input`s so if the user was to submit you would get nothing submitted (as you will do in my example)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I really want. One more thing: how do I put a default value?

Comment: @DiogoPereira add `value="0"` to the `input`s where `0` is your default submit value - you should match it to the `value` attribute in your slider initialisation

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
 $( ".amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
        }
    });
    $( "input[type="hidden"]"  ).val( "$" + $( ".slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
```

to

```
 $( "input['text']" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
        }
    });
    $( "input[type="hidden"]" ).val( "$" + $( ".slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
```

Test it by changing the hidden fields to text.